# Configuring ASP.NET Boilerplate Authorization

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I'm studying the use of ASP.NET Boilerplate and I've noticed that the ASP.NET Boilerplate authorization mechanism uses Attributes like this:

```
[AbpAuthorize("CanDeletePerson")]
public async Task DeletePerson(EntityDto input)
{
   await _personRepository.DeleteAsync(input.Id);
}
```

Let's say for example a person named 'Clay' who has the `CanDeletePerson` permission set. Then subsequently this permission is removed.  How do I add back the permission?

Is there some administration system / UI set-up in the free Abp templates that allows for the configuration and maintenance of User Permissions?

Comment: Permission names are defined in code. Module Zero templates encourage the use of Roles instead of configuring User Permissions directly. If you want to do otherwise, you have to implement the UI yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to add permission to DB, by code you can follow these steps:

- In File .Core\Authorization\AspNetMvc5StartUpTemplateAuthorizationProvider.cs, add a line:

  context.CreatePermission("CanDeletePerson", L("CanDeletePerson"));
- Add localization text in .Core\Localization\Source
- Open web UI then goto Roles menu -> edit a role and where you will see your new permission and add it to a role.

Hope it help.
Cheers

Comment: Thanks,it works.but i have no idea how it works in the program. i should take a closer look.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware only the premium [template](https://aspnetzero.com/Documents/Abp-Template-vs-AspNet-Zero) has a pre-built UI for you to use from the outset.

With the free version we have to build Permission admin pages ourselves.

There is a class called 'HostRoleAndUserCreator'.  Find that class and you will see how RolePermissionSetting are persisted/initialised.

You will also see from your *MyApp*AuthorizationProvider how permissions themselves are seeded.

Comment: ,thank you for the response.But do you have any good idea to configure those like "CanDeletePerson,CanAddPerson etc.." in class AbpAuthorize here?